# Display error message and resume loop

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop, error-handling

I have created a VBA Macro code to generate emails with different recipients, subjects, mail content, attachments etc using various criterion...

The code works fine, EXCEPT when there is an issue with the attachments. When the macro fails to find a relevant file at the given location, it gives a popup message BUT DOES NOT progress the loop further.

My questions is, if anyone could please see where should the "Next" and "Exit Sub" be placed so as to keep on looping and generating "Error Popups" together with the "Email drafts" without stopping the code.

Thanks in advance...

Please find the code below...

```
Sub Email_Creation_Tool()
    On Error GoTo ErrMsg
    Dim wbk As Workbook
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object, signature As String
    Dim i As Range, j As Long
    Dim objItem As Object

    With ActiveSheet
        Set i = Range("A2", Range("A2").End(xlDown))
        For j = 1 To i.Rows.Count
            Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
            If Cells(j + 1, 1).Value <> "" Then
                Mailto = Cells(j + 1, 3).Value

                If Mailto = "Sentence No. 1" Then
                    Mailto = "Friend1@abc.com"
                    MailSubject = Cells(j + 1, 1).Value & " Sentence No. 1"
                    MailBody = " Hi blah blah "
                End If

                If Mailto = "Sentence No. 2” Then
                    Mailto = "Friend2@abc.com; Friend3@abc.com"
                    CCTo = "CommonFriend@abc.com"
                    MailSubject = Cells(j + 1, 1).Value & " Sentence No. 2"
                    MailBody = "Hi blah blah,"
                End If

                If Mailto = "Sentence No. 2” Then
                    MailSubject =  Cells(j + 1, 1).Value & " Sentence No. 3"
                    Mailto = "Friend2@abc.com; Friend3@abc.com"
                    CCTo = "CommonFriend@abc.com"
                    MailBody = " Hi blah blah "      
                End If

                Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
                Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(o)
                With OutMail
                    .Display
                    signature = OutMail.body

                    With OutMail
                        .Subject = MailSubject
                        .To = Mailto
                        .CC = CCTo
                        .body = MailBody & vbNewLine & signature


                        Name "D:\Users\MY_PC\Desktop\" & Cells(j + 1, 1).Value & ".txt" As "D:\Users\MY_PC\Desktop\" & Cells(j + 1, 1).Value & "_trial.txt"
                        Attach = "D:\Users\MY_PC\Desktop\" & Cells(j + 1, 1).Value & "_trial.txt"
                        .Attachments.Add (Attach)

                        Exit Sub 'where should this be placed
                        On Error Resume Next  'where should this be placed

                    End With
                    Set OutMail = Nothing
                    Set OutApp = Nothing
                End With
            End If

            On Error Resume Next 'where should this be placed

            ErrMsg:

            MsgBox ("Attachment WP" & (Cells(j + 1, 1).Value) & vbNewLine & _
            "Not Found/Name Incorrect")
        Next j
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I edited your code "slightly", give it a try :

**EDIT**
What I changed is, I used "Select case" instead of multiple "Ifs", as you have multiple If's options. Then I added ".Save" and ".Close olpromptforsave" to save and close message window, in case it has attachment or no. Goto is good for jumping through code, like in this case.

So logic is:

if you don't find file to attach, skip to error message, then continues with nextJ code: save and close, proceed to another "j" (nextJ code runs no matter if file is found or not)

If you find file to attach, attach it, save, close, skip error message and  continue to another "j"

```
Sub Email_Creation_Tool()
Dim wbk As Workbook
Dim OutApp As Object, OutMail As Object, objItem As Object
Dim i As Integer, j As Long, signature As String

For j = 2 To Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
  If Cells(j + 1, 1).Value <> vbNullString Then
Mailto = Cells(j + 1, 3).Value

select case Mailto
    case "Sentence No. 1"
        Mailto = "Friend1@abc.com"
        MailSubject = Cells(j + 1, 1).Value & " Sentence No. 1"
        MailBody = " Hi blah blah "
    case "Sentence No. 2"
        Mailto = "Friend2@abc.com; Friend3@abc.com"
        CCTo = "CommonFriend@abc.com"
        MailSubject = Cells(j + 1, 1).Value & " Sentence No. 2"
        MailBody = "Hi blah blah,"
    case "Sentence No. 3"
        MailSubject =  Cells(j + 1, 1).Value & " Sentence No. 3"
        Mailto = "Friend2@abc.com; Friend3@abc.com"
        CCTo = "CommonFriend@abc.com"
        MailBody = " Hi blah blah "
End Select

Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
With OutMail
    .Display
    signature = OutMail.body
    .Subject = MailSubject
    .To = Mailto
    .CC = CCTo
    .body = MailBody & vbNewLine & signature
    Attach = "D:\Users\MY_PC\Desktop\" & Cells(j + 1, 1).Value & "_trial.txt"
    If Dir(Attach) = vbNullString then GoTo ErrMsg
    .Attachments.Add (Attach)
    GoTo nextJ
ErrMsg:
MsgBox ("Attachment WP " & (Cells(j + 1, 1).Value) & vbNewLine & "Not Found/Name Incorrect")
nextJ:
.Save
.Close olpromptforsave
End With
End If
Next j

Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Dear user2250595, thanks for the solution !.. But I would just like to know a brief explanation of how you fixed it :)

Comment: Marked !...Many Thanks user2250595, BTW is that your real name ? :D

Comment: One little thing I would want to add here...
     Name "D:\Users\MY_PC\Desktop\" & Cells(j + 1, 1).Value & ".txt" As "D:\Users\MY_PC\Desktop\" & Cells(j + 1, 1).Value & "_trial.txt"

was given on purpose to rename the attachment :) Anyways I would add this statement before the "Attach" statement.

Answer (score 0):

Try using **Go to** statement [Please look into this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/69whc95c.aspx)

Comment: Please click on the link **Please look into this link** (in my answer) and let me know if anything is not clear.